# numpy *= not working

Tags: python, numpy

I use numpy to calculate matrix multiply.
If I use t = t * x, it works just fine, but if I use t *= x, it doesn't.
Do I need to use t = t * x?

```
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = [
        [0.9, 0.075, 0.025],
        [0.15, 0.8, 0.05],
        [0.25, 0.25, 0.5]
    ]
    t = [1, 0, 0]
    x = np.matrix(x)
    t = np.matrix(t)
    t = t * x  # work , [[ 0.9    0.075  0.025]]
    # t *= x  # not work? always [[0 0 0]]
    print t
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You filled `t` with ints rather than floats, so NumPy decides you want a matrix of integer dtype. When you do `t *= x`, this requests that the operation be performed in place, reusing the `t` object to store the result. This forces the results to be cast to integers, so they can be stored in `t`.

Initialize `t` with floats:

```
t = numpy.matrix([1.0, 0.0, 0.0])
```

I would also recommend switching to plain arrays, rather than matrices. The convenience of `*` over `dot` isn't worth the inconsistencies `matrix` causes. If you're on Python 3.5 or later, you can even use `@` for matrix multiplication with regular arrays.